# Помогите разобраться с реверсом байт

Tags: java, битовые-операции

Задание:

> Реализуйте функцию Reverse, которая на вход принимает массив байт, выполняет битовый реверс каждого байта в массиве и выводит результат на экран.

Не понимаю как решить.

Comment: Развернуть байт - на крайний случай, можно таблицу на 256 элементов завести.

Comment: @KoVadim Что в нём крайнего? отличный подход...

Comment: Битовый реверс - это замена 0 на 1 и 1 на 0? Тогда byte = byte ^ 0xFF вам в помощь

Comment: нет, это первый бит стает последним и наоборот

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть алгоритма проста, несмотря на видимую сложность кода:

1. меняем соседние биты байта
2. меняем соседние пары бит
3. меняем соседние четвёрки бит

---

```
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    byte[] arr = {5, 10, 100, -10};
    revers(arr);
  }
  public static void revers (byte[] args)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
      int tmp = (int)args[i];
      tmp = ((tmp & 0x55) << 1) | ((tmp >> 1) & 0x55);
      tmp = ((tmp & 0x33) << 2) | ((tmp >> 2) & 0x33);
      tmp = ((tmp & 0x0F) << 4) | ((tmp >> 4) & 0x0F);
      System.out.format("# %d Byte revers to %d\n",args[i],(byte)tmp);
      args[i] = (byte)tmp;
   }    
 }  
}
```

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/0kW2qo)

```
# 5 Byte revers to -96
# 10 Byte revers to 80
# 100 Byte revers to 38
# -10 Byte revers to 111
```

На ECMAScript(JS) можно так, через строки.. 
например предположим что у нас Byte без знака

// преобразовываем байт в двоичную строку
// нормализация слева нулями и берём последние 8 символов строки
// разделяем строку на массив знаков 0,1
// реверс массива
// "склеиваем" массив обратно в строку 
// преобразовываем ее в число по двоичной системе

```js
var arr = [5, 10, 255, 254];
console.log(invert(arr));

function invert(arr) {
  for (i in arr) {
    var elemstring = ("0000000" + arr[i].toString(2)).slice(-8);
    arr[i] = parseInt(elemstring.split('').reverse().join(''), 2);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int reverse(int number){
    return ~number;
}
```

Например, если послать 10 (`1010` в двоичной), то вернет -11 (`1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0101` в двоичной).

[Источник](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)